# Dependency unpacking in leiningen project

Tags: clojure, dependencies, leiningen

I have a leiningen project which has a dependency which:

- exists in my local `~/.m2/repository`
- has a classifier (i.e. info)
- has an extension of `.tar.gz`

I want to copy that dependency to a subdirectory of my project and unpack it (i.e. `tar zxvf`).

I have looked around for a plugin which will do this, but none of them seem orientated at non-jar files (i.e. `lein-unpack-resource`), and others seem to copy dependencies of dependencies (i.e. `lein-libdir`).

Is there a leiningen way of doing this? In maven, I would use the `dependency:unpack` goal of the maven dependency plugin.

Thanks in advance.